# Xamarin Forms - negate bool binding values

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am learning the xamarin forms and mvvm pattern. I am wondering, if is it possible to negate binding bool value. What I mean is:

I have, let's say Entry with isVisible Binding:

```
<Entry
    x:Name="TextEntry"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleEntry}"
/>
```

and `Label` which i want to hide when `TextEntry` is visible.

```
<Label x:Name="MainLabel" 
       isVisible="!{Binding IsVisibleEntry}"/> //ofc it is not working
```

Is it possible to do without making a new variable for MainLabel in ViewModel?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Option One: Converter

#### Define the converter:

```cs
    public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !((bool)value);
        }
    
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

#### Usage in XAML:

```xml
    <Label x:Name="MainLabel" 
           isVisible="{Binding IsVisibleEntry, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"/>
```

#### XAML Header

```xml
    xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:HikePOS.Helpers"
```

## Option Two: Trigger

```xml
    <Label x:Name="MainLabel" isVisible="{Binding IsVisibleEntry}">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsVisibleEntry}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
```

Comment: Which one is preferable?

Comment: I would go for option 1, it also works in e.g. a ListView etc so will keep your code cleaner and leaner

Comment: This is an old answer, but ConvertBack should also have `return !((bool)value);` in it's body.

Comment: For Option Two: Trigger, I had to not have this:    isVisible="{Binding IsVisibleEntry}"  in the <Label> element.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of writing your own converter, you could use [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) which now has a converter [invertedboolconverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/invertedboolconverter) that can be used out of the box. This example (taken from Microsoft's documentation) shows how it works:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyLittleApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>

        <Label IsVisible="{Binding MyBooleanValue, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: wicked. thanx very much

Comment: Maybe Im having a bad day, but every time I try googling this I end up resigning and just declaring another boolean, e.g. IsRunning and IsNotRunning... how "!" in c# can translate to 7-8 lines of ugly xml is not something I will ever be able to comprehend...

Answer (score 13):

You will need to create an Invert converter so your binding would look somewhat like this:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

In your XAML

```
<local:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="inverter"/>
<Entry
x:Name="TextEntry"
IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleEntry, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}"
/>
```

Comment: On a few occasions I have waisted a few hours trying to get this to work, and I never have. I always get `Type core:InverseBoolConverter not found in xmlns Igs.Mobile.Core` or equivalent to how I named things.

Comment: Are you sure ConvertBack will return !value?  Because the accepted answer just returns value.

Comment: @GautamJain - the accepted answer is wrong - it should invert both places. However, it only matters if you use "two-way binding" on the value. Otherwise, ConvertBack is never called.

Answer (score 2):

I like the answers that are provided already, but I thought I'd add my own version that I've been using sometimes. With the MVVM architecture, the View Model's properties are all calling `SetProperty()` in the object setters, which raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. What I've been doing is adding a second property to the view model, and setting its value to `!value` in the setter of the first property.

For example, I want a button to be `button.IsEnabled = false` whenever the property `ViewModel.IsBusy = true` is the case. This is a reverse bool example, just like you're asking about.

ViewModel.cs properties:

```
private bool enableButton;
public bool EnableButton
{
    get { return enableButton; }
    set { SetProperty(ref enableButton, value); }
}
private bool isBusy;
bool IsBusy
{
    get { return isBusy; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref isBusy, value);
        EnableButton = !value;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

<Button Text="Start Sync"
        Command="{Binding SyncCommand}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButton}"/>
```

This way, anytime in my code that I call `IsBusy = true`, it will simultaneously set `button.IsEnabled = false`, solving the reverse bool problem.

Comment: the OP is asking if it's possible without adding new variable/property, what you did will add 1 variable and 1 property which is enableButton and EnableButton and that is what the OP is trying to avoid

Comment: I actually like this solution best.  One line is missing though: private bool enableButton;

Comment: Adjustment made.

Answer (score 2):

Although @praty's solution works, if you are using a Custom Control/View or XCT's Popup like myself. Before using converters in our XAML, we need to specify like this:

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <converters:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="invrerseBoolConverter" />
</ContentView.Resources>
```

Hence the final code will be:

**InverseBoolConverter.cs**

```cs
// Under namespace MyProject.Converters

public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

**XAML Code**

```xml
<xct:Popup ...
           xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
           xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
           ...>

    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.Resources>
            <converters:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="inverseBoolConverter" />
        </ContentView.Resources>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleLabel, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolConverter}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</xct:Popup>
```

**NB:** Although we can use Xamarin Community Toolkit's InvertedBoolConverter, I have described manual solution so that we can add custom value converters other than the built-in converters.