# Add element to XAML page whiles in Task.Delay()

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin.forms, task

I'm building a chatbot app with chat bubbles for incoming and outgoing messages. For the incoming messages, I've given it a `Task.Delay()` and now I'd like to give it an `ActivityIndicator` every time before the message pops up (i.e. I want to show the activity indicator whiles the message is being delayed). I've added the activity indicator to the XAML of the incoming messages control;
**IncomingMessageItemControl**

```
<ViewCell
    x:Class="BluePillApp.Controls.IncomingMessageItemControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:pancake="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Grid x:Name="Gridoo">
        <pancake:PancakeView
            Margin="10,10,80,10"
            Padding="15"
            BackgroundColor="#53ffc6"
            CornerRadius="20,20,0,20"
            HasShadow="False"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

            <Label
                FontSize="Medium"
                Text="{Binding Text}"
                TextColor="#1a1a1a" />
        </pancake:PancakeView>

        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" />
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

The problem is, in the ChatbotMessagingPage, the send button is pressed then an outgoing message is sent before getting a reply/incoming message and I've done this in MVVM like so;
**ChatbotMessagingPageViewModel**

```
//This gets the chatbots response for each message
            chatbot.MainUser.ResponseReceived += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = args.Response.Text, User = App.ChatBot });
            };
        }

        #region CLASS METHODS
        /// <summary>
        /// This function sends a message
        /// </summary>
        public void Send()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextToSend))
            {
                var msgModel = new ChatMessageModel() { Text = TextToSend, User = App.User };

                //This adds a new message to the messages collection
                Messages.Add(msgModel);

                var result = chatbot.Evaluate(TextToSend);
                result.Invoke();

                //Removes the text in the Entry after message is sent
                TextToSend = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Everytime I press the send button the ActivityIndicator comes along with the IncomingMessage, I'd like the ActivityIndicator to come first, whiles the IncomingMessage is being delayed.

Comment: Since you've already got the message there is no point in delaying in addition of message, rather delay the presentation of the elements. You could do fading animations - [Xamarin Forms Animation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/)

Comment: I wouldn't want to delay in addition of a message. Each message has a delay before being shown, what I want is for an Activity Indicator to pop up as it is being delayed

Comment: Then you should have a different strategy all together... have the busy cursor at footer of the list, show when waiting for message... simple, lemme know if you need anymore help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that that view cell is the message bubble.

When you do:

```
Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = args.Response.Text, User = App.ChatBot });
```

Your collection is updated and your ListView or whatever hold those ViewCelss is also updated. The `ActivityIndicator` is part of the `ViewCell` so it comes at the same time as the message.

**[OPTION 1] Using an additional flag**

What you can do is create a flag `IsBusy` or `IsDelay` or something and bind the visibility of the ActivityIndicator and Label to it:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="Gridoo">
    <pancake:PancakeView
        Margin="10,10,80,10"
        Padding="15"
        BackgroundColor="#53ffc6"
        CornerRadius="20,20,0,20"
        HasShadow="False"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

        <Label
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="{Binding Text}"
            TextColor="#1a1a1a"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}""> />
    </pancake:PancakeView>

    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
</Grid>
```

Note that I've used a `IValueConverter` to negate the value for the label. In case you're not familiar with it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315807/xamarin-forms-negate-bool-binding-values)

What's left is to add the flag in your `ViewModel`:

```cs
IsBusy = true; // this will make the activity indicator visible, but not the Label
// Also note that you first need to add the message
Messages.Add(new ChatMessageModel() { Text = args.Response.Text, User = App.ChatBot }); 
await Task.Delay(1500);
IsBusy = false; // this will hige the activity indicator visible, and make Label visible
```

So basically the logic is the following:

1. You add the message to your chat BUT the actual text is hidden when on the other hand, the activity indicator is visible.
2. You apply the delay
3. Delay ends, you change the visibility of both views.

Note that in my example I've not declared where that flag is since I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks like. It could be added to ChatMessageModel or `ChatMessageViewModel` since you would need a flag for each message.

**[OPTION 2] in IncomingMessageItemControl.xaml.cs**

A better solution could be to handle it in the code behind of your control. The issue is the same, the activity indicator and the label comes at the same time.

To fix this you can move the delay in `IncomingMessageItemControl.xaml.cs`.
First, you need to add `x:Name` to both the activity indicator and the label.

Then you could do:

```cs
private async Task ChangeVisibilityAsync()
{
    Label.IsVisibe= false;
    ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    Label.IsVisibe = true;
    ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
}
```