# InverseBoolConverter is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension. XLS0505 XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

I am working with Xamarin Forms and trying to implement a loading overlay that would display text show the spinny thing and disable buttons.

Since buttons need to be disabled when loading [I am trying to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315807/xamarin-forms-negate-bool-binding-values#answer-46316024) `InverseBoolConverter`

It works ok on iOS (gives a warning but I am too cool to care), Android gives an error instead,
`Error  XLS0505 Type 'Helpers:InverseBoolConverter' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension.`
and the build mechanism is not cool enough to build it, so I have a problem.

XAML:

```
xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:xxx.MobileApp.Converters"
....

<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,-80,30,24" Spacing="10">
            <Image x:Name="previewImage" Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" IsVisible="false" />
            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Padding="20"
                    Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                    Text="&#xf030;"
                    FontSize="40"
                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenCameraCommand}"                        
                    Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonWhiteText}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"/>
            <Button Padding="20"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                    Text="&#xf302;"
                    FontSize="40"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenGaleryCommand}"     
                    Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonWhiteText}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
    <StackLayout 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        
        <Label Text="Downloading the metadata"
               TextColor="Black"
               IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </Label>
        <ActivityIndicator 
        Color="Black"
        Scale="5"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

converter:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Surely this is a known problem, and someone has already laid a path on, how to fix it?**

Comment: did you define it in the Resources?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/invertedboolconverter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use it as a markup extension the converter implementation needs to implement `IMarkupExtension<IValueConverter>` [Creating XAML Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating), otherwise you can use it the classic way as a `StaticResource`.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
      <Helpers:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter "/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<Button Padding="20"
                    Margin="0,0,0,5" 
                    Text="&#xf030;"
                    FontSize="40"
                    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenCameraCommand}"                        
                    Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonWhiteText}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"/>
            <Button Padding="20"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                    Text="&#xf302;"
                    FontSize="40"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenGaleryCommand}"     
                    Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonWhiteText}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"/>
```

An easier approach is using the existing stuff (not to reinvent the wheel),
[invertedboolconverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/invertedboolconverter) from [XamarinCommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) package.

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"

 <Button Padding="20"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                    Text="&#xf302;"
                    FontSize="40"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={xct:InvertedBoolConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenGaleryCommand}"     
                    Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonWhiteText}" 
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"/>
```

[InvertedBoolConverter source code](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Converters/InvertedBoolConverter.shared.cs)

Comment: Hi Cfun, thanks for the answer. After adding toolkit I am now getting `
Error NETSDK1136 The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so. `xxx.Tests C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets 362 
` Have you seen this one before?

Comment: no never encounter this before, Are you targeting wpf ?

Comment: No xamarin only

Comment: Android and iOS no UWP or anything else

Comment: in which project(s) have you installed the toolkit ?

Comment: into MobileApp only, one with the common views VMs and stuff.

Comment: What is the type/Target framework of that project ?

Comment: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: Sorry about that I have no clue, you may get better help by opening another question here or in the official repo https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/discussions

Comment: Thanks, Chun, I will do it tomorrow, it is weird thought that the test project would fail.

Comment: You're welcome, I remember I see something related to test projects I believe it's the same issue you have: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1167

Comment: A workaround in that issue stated "Changing the test project from .Net 5 to netCore 3.1 allows it to build."

Comment: Hi Cfun, switching to 3.1 did it. Thanks.

Comment: The `StaticResource` option worked for me (thanks @Cfun!) but I had to give the `x:Key` value a different name, as `InverseBoolConverter` clashed with the class name.